# SSRS get todays datetime as a constant value on each page

Tags: datetime, reporting-services

I created a simple placeholder with the expression: `=Now()` in my footer.

But this value changes whenever I go to a new page. E.g. page 1 has 3:08:34, and page 2 has 3:11:35. See screenshot below.

[image]

Then I scroll to page 2:

[image]

The time increased by about 3 minutes when scrolling from page 1 to 2.

The same happens when I export to PDF, although the difference is only a few seconds rather than minutes.

I'm using *MSSMS 17* and doing the report in *Visual Studio 17*

---

**How can I get a static datetime when the report is executed?**

i.e. I want the same datetime on every page.

Comment: Not 100% sure this will work, but you can try creating a parameter and setting the default value to `=Now()` and instead of having the expression in the placeholder you would have the parameter `[@param]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built in value `Globals!ExecutionTime` instead of Now(). This is a single constant value.

Something liek

```
= Format(Globals!ExecutionTime,"dd/MM/yyyy  h:mm:ss")
```

Comment: thanks! Works great. Do you know if there  some sort refresh variable causing now() to reevaluate, or is that just the nature of that function?

Comment: I think now() is just reevaluated when it is called. So if you have several pages, they are only rendered when you view each page or when it is written to a PDF etc. If you wait 1 minute before viewing page 2 I would expect it to show the time 1 min later than page one. The global variable is evaluated once when the report is executed so it remains the same for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, I tried to create a parameter with now() as default value and then added this on footer, which remain static on each page.
Also if you could see below images  I also added another text box with =now() as direct expression and this changed on each page.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for the screenshot! This is a great work around to the Globals!ExecutionTime mentioend by Alan Schofield.